# Adding a new relationship to an existing model in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm developing an iOS application using Realm and have a object MedicationObject which contains the information about the Medication being used. This then has a many to one relationship class MedicationRecording which stores the information when the time the medication was taken.

```
    import Foundation
    import RealmSwift
    class MedicationObject : Object {
    //This model requires a Primary Key
    @objc dynamic var id = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
    @objc dynamic var medicationName : String = ""

    //stores the refrences to medication recoridngs

    var messurements = List<MedicationRecording>()

    public func addNewMesurment() {
        print(self)
        let medicationRecording = MedicationRecording()
        medicationRecording.medicationTaken = self
        medicationRecording.timeTaken = Date()// this saves the time to now
        medicationRecording.medicationTaken = self

        RealmAccess().updateMedicationObject(medicationObject: self, medicationRecord: medicationRecording) //this should work
    }
    }
```

here is my MedicationRecording:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
class MedicationRecording : Object {
    @objc  dynamic var medicationTaken : MedicationObject? = MedicationObject()
    @objc  dynamic var timeTaken : Date = Date()
    @objc dynamic var id = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

}
```

and this is the method I'm calling to save the data to

```
        func updateMedicationObject(medicationObject : MedicationObject, medicationRecord : MedicationRecording) {
        let realm = try! getRealmAccess()
        let mediObject = MedicationObject()
        mediObject.medicationName = medicationObject.medicationName
        do {
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(medicationRecord, update: true)
                medicationObject.messurements.append(medicationRecord)

        }
        }
    }
```

At the moment when I'm saving the data it is then losing all the information in MedicationObject and only saving the last data.
Any help with be greatly appreciated
Thank you

Comment: There are several issues with your code. Why are you creating a to-one relationship in `MedicationRecording` to a `MedicationObject` when you should only be holding references to `MedicationRecording`s in the `MedicationObject` intances. Moreover, your one-to-one relationship is declared incorrectly, it shouldn't be marked `@objc dynamic`. Your `updateMedicationObject` function also declares `mediObject` for no reason.

Comment: Hello, thanks @DávidPásztor I've removed the one-to-one relationship from Medical Recording and its seemed to resolved the issue of the object being cleared, but at the moment it is still not saving. What do I need to fix that and have the relationship updated? Thank you!

Comment: @DávidPásztor I got it working! Thank you!